# Fast Two Sample Test for Bivariate Distributions

Tags: distributions, joint-distribution, two-sample

I have several thousand datasets of the same two variables (X and Y) and each dataset has at least 5,000 samples.  I need to perform two-sample tests between many combinations of these datasets (total of about 10,000 tests) to determine whether or not the relationship between X and Y is different between two datasets.

Their relationship may be non-linear, and I do not care about differences in mean--all I care about is their relationship.  More concretely, for example, I would need a test that can distinguish between the four datasets in [Anscombe's Quartet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet)--except I have several thousand datasets.

I applied the [Kernel Two Sample Test](http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/~gretton/mmd/mmd.htm) (i.e. Maximum Mean Discrepancy), as implemented by [kernlab](https://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/kernlab/html/kmmd.html), to good effect: it distinguishes the relationship between X and Y across different datasets.  However, it is just too slow.  I also feel like it is "overkill" in some sense.  I only have two dimensions, do I really need these kernel based methods?

I almost wonder if just doing histogram-based density estimation and then taking the L2 distance between the two densities would be just as good.

Are there other methods I should consider?  Or should I invest the time to try and speed up the kernel MMD (there are several papers that claim to do so)?

Comment: Did you consider a two-sample K-S test applied to $Y-X$?

Comment: Thanks @jth, is that a common approach?  I have never heard of applying K-S to the difference of the two dimensions. I had written  off K-S because I know there are problems with multidimensional datasets.  Is there anything I could read about this approach or why it work be a good choice here?

Comment: I doubt it's standard, it just struck me as something that would distinguish between the various Anscombe datasets (with a lot more data).